# Extract all occurences of a substring from a string

Tags: apex, merge-field, substring

hello guys how would i extract all instances  of a substring pattern given a 
string.  e.g 
`given a string templateContent = 'hello adrian , this is for {!Contact.Name} to be delivered to {!Account.ShippingAddress}';.` how would i extract all instances of the substrings that have this pattern `{!FirstWord.SecondWord}`. please note that i am also allowing for punctuation blunders from the users that enter that string. for example a user can type in `{!Contact.FirstName}{!Order.Date}` (in this case the error being that there is no space between the words. using split would'nt be so effective for this use case from my experience) .

ive been trying to wrap my head around this but i am yet to . Please help . Thank you all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a simple "regular expression" situation. You can use the following code as a starting point:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\{!.+?\\}');
string templateContent = 'hello adrian , this is for {!Contact.Name} to be delivered to {!Account.ShippingAddress}';
Matcher m = p.matcher(templateContent);
while(m.find()) {
    System.debug(m.group(0));
}
```

Where `\\{!.+?\\}` means:

- Find `{!`
- Followed by any character (`.`) at least once (`+`), the minimum number of times possible (`?`) to the next part.
- Find `}`

This will work even when the `{!...}` is immediately followed by another one.

Comment: Thank you.. that was exactly what i was trying to get my head around

Comment: this works whenever i use it in the execute anonymous.. but when i try to run it in an apex method from a vf page, it doesnt work ... i get an internal regex error .. any reason why ?

Comment: Invalid regex: Unexpected internal error near index 7 \{!.+?\

Comment: i found my error i guess... i think in the apex controller i was missing the '}' character while in the exec anonymous it was there